# How to launch a pop up when a user clicks close on a Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, exit, joptionpane

I have a `JFrame` that currently has `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Is it possible for me to change this so that when the user clicks close I launch an *"Are you sure?"* `JOptionPane` style pop up?

How can I do this?

Comment: Yes,it is possible. Simply add an action event for the same!

Comment: @shekharsuman could you provide some example code?

Comment: Here is the similar one,here you go--->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210972/setdefaultcloseoperation-to-show-a-jframe-instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `WindowListener`.  Here's an example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Sure?");

                if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    frame.dispose();
                }
            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```